# Rails - Bootstrap footer disappears?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

so i have a pretty normal setup inside my application.html.erb file:

```
<html class="h-100">

 !head, title, scripts, stylesheets removed for this example here on stackoverflow!

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">



<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <header>

    <%= render 'shared/nav' %>
     <div class="container">
      <%= render partial: 'shared/message' %>
     </div>

  </header>

  <main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
      <%= yield %>
  </main>

   <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>hello</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

That looks good to me. However, the footer is not visible! In fact, it completely disappears when i visit a page. When i inspect the footer via developer tool, it's not even listed inside there.

But for some odd reasons on some pages the footer becomes visible and is then also listed in the developer tool, like it normally should.

My initial thought was that an old scaffold.scss file was causing that and i removed the file entirely, however, that didn't made any changes at all.

I have no errors whatsoever. Never had this kind of issue before. I've searched my app.scss file for any .footer classes, body, html or any other classes that could overwrite the css from bootstrap, but couldn't find anything (used search tool in vscode).

EDIT:

It seems like my html and the body is only 760px in height, however, the main is full width (over 2000px).

I've tried to add `html, body { height: 100%; }`, but even with that height is still just 760px in height. That seems to be the issue, since the pages that show the footer are not higher than 760px.

Any ideas what could cause that problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this same kind of issue:

I've simply moved a few scripts under the <%= yield %>. For some reasons, they were hiding my footer. One of the scripts initializes a sticky chat bar at the bottom, i suspect this particular script is causing the problem. By moving all suspected scripts into the main part, the footer is now finally rendered!

Updated main part (removed scripts for showcase purposes):

```
<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
      <%= yield %>

      <script></script>

  </main>
```

Greetings!